# Java based Selenium2: find element by preceding-sibling when source contains same element two times

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a text related input with preceding-sibling node my HTML is the following:

```
   <FORM id="formid" onsubmit="" method=post name="formid" action=>
      <TABLE width="100%">
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD rowSpan=3><INPUT onclick="" value=1 type=radio name="formid">upbutton1</TD>
            <TD>Pearl</TD>
            <TD rowSpan=3></TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD>ravenclawn</TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD>ravenclawn</TD>
         </TR>
         </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      </TD></TR>
      <TR>
         <TD> </TD>
      </TR>
      </TBODY></TABLE>
      <TABLE width="100%" >
      <TBODY>
         <TR>
            <TD class="someclass"></TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>
            <TD>
               <TABLE class=foo width="100%" border="1px">
      <TBODY>
         <TR class=foo-header>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD><BR></TD>
            <TD colSpan=3></TD>
            <TD></TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-odd>
            <TD><INPUT value=0 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick1</TD>
            <TD>1234</TD>
            <TD>blue </TD>
            <TD colSpan=2>apple2</TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"></TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD><INPUT value=1 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick2</TD>
            <TD>1235 </TD>
            <TD>blue </TD>
            <TD colSpan=2>apple3</TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"> </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-odd>
            <TD><INPUT value=2 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick3</TD>
            <TD>1235</TD>
            <TD>sometext </TD>
            <TD>Pearl</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"> </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD><INPUT value=3 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick4</TD>
            <TD>1236 </TD>
            <TD>blue </TD>
            <TD colSpan=2>apple4</TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"> </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-odd>
            <TD><INPUT value=4 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick5</TD>
            <TD>1236 </TD>
            <TD>sometext </TD>
            <TD>ravenclawn</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"> </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-even>
            <TD><INPUT value=5 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick6</TD>
            <TD>1237 </TD>
            <TD>blue </TD>
            <TD colSpan=2>apple6</TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"> </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class=foo-odd>
            <TD><INPUT value=6 type=radio name="formid.samename">buttonclick7</TD>
            <TD>1237 </TD>
            <TD>sometext </TD>
            <TD>ravenclawn</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD> <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name="samenameagain"></tD>
   </DIV>
```

My target is to click on second Pearl text related input field
Selenium code is the following:

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[contains(text(),'Pearl')][1]/preceding-sibling::td")).click();
```

Problem:
Above code always working with first table that contains Pearl text

Observations:

- That case when im modify first Pearl text to something else the code working fine
- That case when im working with another text ect:"ravenclawn" its working fine without any modifications

Thanks for any advice

Comment: "Click the second Pearl text related input field" -> but your XPath ends with a `td`...?

Comment: yes, its ends with a TD but its works with input too when click() command used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just include index for table also.

```
For 1st table
By.xpath("//table[1]//td[contains(text(),'Pearl')]/preceding-sibling::td")

For 2nd table
By.xpath("//table[2]//td[contains(text(),'Pearl')]/preceding-sibling::td")
```

Comment: Its works fine with the HTML above,but table is populated,but it helped me in the final solution, thank you